# How to reduce VOC of solar panels to match the MPPT

Tags: solar-cell, high-voltage

My panels have VOC of 36VDC.
I like to connect 5 panels in series. But in such case the total VOC would be as high as 180V, and damage my Charge Controller.
Is there any dummy load, or  shunt kind of thing which I could attach between the panels and Charge controller, so that at no time there is a ZERO load, and thus keep my MPPT safe.

Comment: Instead of a dummy load which will waste power, why don't you find a switching regulator that will convert the variable DC voltage to a more manageable and stable working voltage. For instance, a lot of AC adapters are totally capable of working with DC and are rated at 110V DC to well over 180VDC.

Comment: More info, please. Is your Charge Controller able to handle 5 panels in series at their normal operating voltage, about 140V? I kinda guess it is not, that it is expecting 36VOC. If that is the case, connect the panels in parallel, not series, to use that Charge Controller.

Comment: This is also a very dangerous (possibly unsafe) situation, lethal voltages in a DIY setup high on a roof somewhere. It would make me darn nervous. If the shock doesn't kill, the fall might.

Comment: I once designed a high-current active switch that would disconnect PV panels if their output voltage exceeded a certain threshold. It was a tricky situation where 99.9% of the time, the panel's open-circuit voltage was within spec, but if it was a very cold night (-10°C), and then in the morning when the sun struck the panels before they warmed up, the total voltage could have been enough to damage something. The real challenge was minimizing power consumption in the switch, without using something like a relay that could fail easily.

Comment: @BobbiBennett - A lot of modern grid-tied inverters use a bunch of panels in series, rather then in parallel. It keeps the cost of copper wiring down (since it doesn't need to be as heavy to carry the equivalent power), and switch-mode parts that work up to 400VDC are common due to the prevalence of SMPSes.

Comment: @ConnorWolf, that is good information. I wish the OP had presented enough details to assure worry-warts like me that they knew (a bit) what they had and what they were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not make sense without extra information.

Why do you want to connect them in series?
Series connection only works properly if all are close to the same current rating.

Why do you want to purposefully waste energy?
What is the voltage range that your MPPT controller WILL tolerate.

Tell us : Voltage and current of each panel under optimum load.
 Characteristics of MPPT controller.
 Load = ?
Why did you want to connect them in series.

Are the panels identical- if so they could be placed in parallel with diodes to share the load.

Even if not identical in Wattage, as long as they have the same nominal Voltage you can parallel them with diodes for isolation and probably have it worK OK. A lower wattage panel will load down quicker and so a larger wattage panel will then contribute more.